# What is the most optimised way for group by two columns with aggregation and storing the result in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I have a huge DataFrame that includes three columns: `kleur`, `merk`, and `prijs`. I want to compute the average of `prijs` per `kleur` for each `merk`. The data looks as follows:

```
occasions.head(15)

    kleur        merk   prijs
0   Zwart     Peugeot  1490.0
1   Zwart  Alfa Romeo  2450.0
2   Grijs        Fiat  3950.0
3   Groen     Hyundai  1250.0
4   Grijs  Mitsubishi  1350.0
5   Grijs      Nissan  5480.0
6    None        Opel  5950.0
7   Zwart     Peugeot  4950.0
8   Zwart     Peugeot  6950.0
9   Beige     Renault  4950.0
10  Groen      Suzuki  2250.0
11   Geel      Toyota  4980.0
12   Geel  Volkswagen  2950.0
13  Blauw  Volkswagen  2950.0
14  Beige        Fiat  7500.0
```

I implimented it is bellows:

```
temp = []

for merk, mk_data in occasions_prijs_df.head(10).groupby(['merk']):
    for kleur, kleur_data in mk_data.groupby('kleur'):
        temp.append({'merk': merk, 'kleur':kleur, 'kleur_count':kleur_data.shape[0],
                     'prijs_avg': kleur_data['prijs'].mean()})
        print merk, kleur, kleur_data.shape[0], kleur_data['prijs'].mean()

occasions_prijs_df_gr = pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

The output (`occasions_prijs_df_gr`) should be as follows:

```
 kleur  kleur_count        merk    prijs_avg
0  Zwart            1  Alfa Romeo  2450.000000
1  Grijs            1        Fiat  3950.000000
2  Groen            1     Hyundai  1250.000000
3  Grijs            1  Mitsubishi  1350.000000
4  Grijs            1      Nissan  5480.000000
5  Zwart            3     Peugeot  4463.333333
6  Beige            1     Renault  4950.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by list of tuples for new columns names by aggregate functions `mean` and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
tup = [('prijs_avg', 'mean'), ('kleur_count','size')]
df = df.groupby(['kleur','merk'])['prijs'].agg(tup).reset_index()
print (df)
    kleur        merk    prijs_avg  kleur_count
0   Beige        Fiat  7500.000000            1
1   Beige     Renault  4950.000000            1
2   Blauw  Volkswagen  2950.000000            1
3    Geel      Toyota  4980.000000            1
4    Geel  Volkswagen  2950.000000            1
5   Grijs        Fiat  3950.000000            1
6   Grijs  Mitsubishi  1350.000000            1
7   Grijs      Nissan  5480.000000            1
8   Groen     Hyundai  1250.000000            1
9   Groen      Suzuki  2250.000000            1
10   None        Opel  5950.000000            1
11  Zwart  Alfa Romeo  2450.000000            1
12  Zwart     Peugeot  4463.333333            3
```